# Is there something comparable to the "result"-variable in Delphi also in Java?

Tags: java, delphi

One of the things I really liked while working with Delphi was that there was a `result` variable for functions. A Delphi function ended like this:

```
result:="My Result";
```

The datatype of the result variable is the return type of the function. No additional code was necessary. Nowadays, when i'm writing stuff in Java, it looks most of the time like this:

```
function List<Foo> myFunc(){
  List<Foo> myResultVar = new ArrayList<>();
  //--now i do some clever stuff--
  return myResultVar;
}
```

As you see, it's some more boilerplate code compared to Delphi at least when you have to write more than a one-liner. Is there something comparable to the `result` variable in Java and i just don't know it?

Comment: You might find Groovy's more to your liking then, rather than 'traditional' Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing like that. The only way of saying what to return in Java is to use the `return` statement.

In your code, why don't you only declare the `myResultVar` at the point where you actually know the value to return? Or if you decide that in various different branches, declare the variable *without* giving it an initial value:

```
int result;
if (something) {
   // Do some work...
   result = foo();
} else {
   // Do some other work...
   result = bar();
}
// Do some post work...
return result;
```

And if you don't need to do anything *after* that, just return immediately then anyway... If you can give a concrete example of some code where you really think that having a special variable makes the code significantly simpler, we could try to write the cleanest valid equivalent code in Java.

Answer (score 1):

No, the syntax of the Java programming language derives from the syntax of the C language, whereas Delphi derives from Pascal.

There is nothing like the Delphi's `result` pseudo-variable.